# SSRS Formatting issue in the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-pdf

> How to display numeric column in the ssrs report with preceding zero
>
> Example:-
>
> I want to display numeric value like 01234 in the report but whenever
> i export to the excel it should display like 1234(without zero).
>
> Tried code:

```
>  have applied many format[Report and PDf ][1] in text box expression for numeric values
> but it worked for both ways either completely convert to  numeric or
> string
```

> have attached the screen shot of the report and the pdf.

#### REPORT AND PDF

[image: REPORT AND PDF]

Answer (score 0):

Add custom code to report:

```
Public Function CustomFormatNumber(ByVal value As Integer, ByVal padZero As Boolean) As Object
    If  padZero Then
        Return "0" & value
    Else
        Return value
    End If
End Function
```

And then set Value expression like this:

```
=Code.CustomFormatNumber(Fields!YourField.Value, Globals!RenderFormat.Name <> "EXCELOPENXML")
```

Comment: hi, thanks for sending the code. i tested this code, its alway display with append zero in the report which is correct but when i export to the excel it does not remove appended zero in the file

Comment: You may be use other rendering extension than EXCELOPENXML. What is extension of file that you get when exporting to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I created a (very) simple dataset with this following SQL:

```
select '01234' as [Value]
```

Then created a text box, and set the Number Format on the text box to be "Number". In the expression on the text box, I used.

```
=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name <> "EXCELOPENXML", cstr(Fields!Value.Value), cint(Fields!Value.Value))
```

The cstr() is probably not required, as the Value is already a string in the SQL.

This puts the Value in string format (keep the 0) when viewing the report or exporting to anything other than Excel, and sets it to be an integer (remove the 0) when exporting to Excel.

Hope this helps.